# How to skip optional parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala

Given the following function with optional parameters:

```
def foo(a:Int = 1, b:Int = 2, c:Int = 3) ...
```

I want to keep the default value of *a* but pass new values to *b* and *c* only by positional assignment (rather than by a named assignment), that is any of the following syntaxes would be nice:

```
foo( , 5, 7)
foo(_, 5, 7)
```

Is something like that possible with Scala?

Comment: Why not label the parameters?

Comment: I am just curious is this even possible in other languages? like Python, R, Java?

Comment: @Tripp: Repeating all parameter names (probably even longer names) at every single function call is annoying. I am lazy :) Further, I think that leaving out an argument is very clear and unambiguous and even simple to implement into a language specification.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. The R language has this feature and it is really very convenient to use.

Comment: `f(_)` is taken, but `f(a = _)` for default args would be neat, by analogy to `var x: Int = _` for default values. Because Scala needs another use for underscore.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. - Perl 5 also has this feature.

Answer (score 15):

There's no way to skip the parameters, but you can use named parameters when you call your `foo` method, for example:

```
// Call foo with b = 5, c = 7 and the default value for a
foo(b = 5, c = 7)
```

*edit* - You asked specifically how to do this by positional assignment: this is not possible in Scala.

Answer (score 4):

You can create another function, with one of the parameters applied.

```
def long(a: Int = 1, b: Int = 2, c: Int = 3) = a + b + c

def short(x: Int, y: Int) = long(b = x, c = y)

val s = short(10, 20) // s: Int = 31
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution (far from pretty) could be [Currying](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying.html)

You would need to change the method signature a little bit:

```
// Just for "a" parameter

def foo(a: Int = 1)(b: Int = 2, c: Int = 3)

foo()(2,3)   // 6
foo(1)(2,3)  // 6
foo(2)(2,3)  // 7
```

For all the parameters:

```
def foo(a: Int = 1)(b: Int = 2)(c: Int = 3) = a + b + c

foo()()(3)   // 6
foo()(2)(3)  // 6
foo(2)()(3)  // 7
foo(3)()(3)  // 8
```

Comment: You can also use `foo.curried` to convert foo into its curried form without changing the method signature.