# Scala source code definition of "def" and other built ins

Tags: scala

I was doing some research of how to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402458/how-to-skip-optional-parameters-in-scala) question. However, I am wondering if I can start learning how the `function` works, or how they pass the argument into the local scope by reading the source code of scala.

I know the source code of scala is hosted in [Github](https://github.com/scala/scala), my question is how to locate the definition of `def`.

Or more generally, how to locate the source code of certain built in functions, operators?

Answer (score 1):

The source code for everything in the Scala standard library is under https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.11.x/src/library/scala.

Also, the Scaladoc for the standard library includes links to the source code. So e.g. if you're interested in `scala.Option` and you're looking at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#scala.Option, notice that page has "Source: Option.scala" where "Option.scala" is hyperlinked to [the source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L1).

For something like `def`, which is not part of the standard library, but part of the language, well... there is no single place where `def` itself is defined. The compiler has 25 phases (you can list them by running `scalac -Xshow-phases`) and basically every phase participates in the job of making `def` mean what it means.

If you want to understand `def`, you'd probably be better off reading the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/); it's highly technical, but still much more approachable than the source code for the compiler.

The part of the spec that addresses your question about named and default arguments is [SLS 6.6.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#named-and-default-arguments).